When is a question a request for service reviews?
One of our site's closing reason reads:

Questions seeking product or service reviews are off-topic because
they tend to attract subjective, low-quality, and spam answers. On
the other hand, offerings in the Bitcoin space are still evolving
rapidly which often renders answers outdated quickly. For more
information see this meta-discussion.

What is meant by "product or service reviews" in this context? When should we vote to close questions under this reason?

Relevant post from the Stack Overflow blog: Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!. Also, a related MSE post: Why was my "shopping list" question closed?

The way I interpret this closing reason, we do not want questions that ask for an evaluation or comparison of services. Examples for off-topic questions:

What's the best exchange in country foo?
How do you like service ABC?
Is X or Y better for Z?
Is ABC a scam?
Let's collect all XYZ by posting one book/service/course/wallet per answer…

These sort of questions inherently subjective and prompt one-line answers, astroturfing, and other answers that quickly outdate.
However, I would consider the following questions legit and on-topic:

How can I do XYZ under these circumstances?
What should I watch out for when I choose a solution provider for that problem I want to solve?

Questions that focus on the how and why prompt answerers to provide expertise. While expertise is still somewhat subjective, it is valuable and non-trivial to come by for new users. Note that these questions still often get low-quality answers, so we should rigorously require answers to such questions to elaborate: how it solves the issue the user is facing, why the answerer is recommending a specific solution, and how they know about it.
